# PHP foreach not working XML

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I don't really understand why this foreach is not working:

```
 <?php
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=hotels+in+newyork&key=AIzaSyAZAkutsge0U-xZVMvwf_Iw_ubdN2bra64";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->result->name as $name)
{

    echo $name;
}
```

it shows only the 1st row!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to loop $xml->result.

```
foreach($xml->result as $result)
{
    echo $result->name;
}
```